# How to merge partitions using Execute Immediate?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to merge the partitions on interval partitioned tables as I cannot drop the partition which got created initially and I am trying to implement it through execute immediate, but not able to get through it. Could you please help me with this.

```
DECLARE
l_tab_date  DATE;
l_arcv_high_value VARCHAR2(300);
l_tab_date_p DATE;
l_tab_date_c DATE;
l_query_trun_arch VARCHAR2(3000);
BEGIN
 SELECT high_value INTO l_arcv_high_value FROM all_tab_partitions WHERE
 table_name='TEST_ARCHIVAL' AND partition_position=1;  
 l_tab_date:= TO_DATE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_arcv_high_value, '[^'']+', 1, 2) ,'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');  
 l_tab_date_p:=TRUNC(l_tab_date-1,'MONTH');
 l_tab_date_c:=TRUNC(l_tab_date, 'MONTH');  
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[ALTER TABLE TEST_ARCHIVAL MERGE PARTITIONS 
           for (to_date(l_tab_date_p,'DD-MM-YYYY')), 
           for  (to_date(l_tab_date_c, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))]';
  END;
 /
```

Comment: what is the main problem? errorcode?

Comment: First solve it without `execute immediate`, then work out how to build the statement dynamically in PL/SQL. For a start it looks as though you have quoted some 'to_date' expressions and local variables instead of concatenating them. ('l_date_tab_p' doesn't mean anything inside `execute immediate`.) Also the neat way to write date literals is `date '2016-01-29'`.